# Intuitive meaning of discriminant as determinant of trace values

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, discriminant

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $n\in\Bbb N$, $R$ be an $A$-algebra which is free $A$-module of rank $n$.
If $x_i\in R$ for $i\lt n$, then the discriminant is defined as:
$$\operatorname{dis}_{R/A}(x_i:i\lt n)=\det(\operatorname{Tr}_{R/A}(x_ix_j):i,j\lt n)$$
Where this definition come from? What's the intuition behind this? There exists a determinant-free equivalent definition?

Comment: Keith Conrad has a nice [set of notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf) on the different ideal, where he makes an analogy between lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the dot product, and lattices in number fields and the trace pairing. Not sure it answers your question, but it's at least related.

Comment: Actually, maybe [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/disc.pdf) are closer to your question. In Remark 3.2, again by thinking of the trace pairing as an algebraic version of the dot product, he says that $\operatorname{disc}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is like the "volume" of the submodule spanned by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.